# Sending data from a secure form to an unsecure form without an alert

Tags: php, forms, submit

Here is my scenario:

I have a facebook page that takes a form and submits it securely to my server.
I then need to pass some (not all) of this data to another un-secure (http) server.
Is there a way I can do this without an alert.
Currently I use php to pass the data from the first form into the second form using hidden fields.

is there a good way to accomplish this without the alert that is caused by the hidden fields submitting to http and not https

I spoke to our service provider and they said there is no way to have our account submit securely so to put data into their server it requires an UN-secure connection.  I realize adding ssl to that address would resolve the issue but I'm wondering if there is a way to do thing on the PHP server side without the passed data using hidden forms to re-submit.

Comment: yes, use curl to send the data to the unsecure server.

Answer (score 0):

You can submit the data of the form to a script in the secure URL, then use cURL to send the data to the un-secure endpoint.

Here is a tutorial: http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post

Hope this helps